# Best design UI for android like Path social network using HTML5 or Native?

Tags: android, html

I want to ask about best design in android like path social network using HTML5 or native?

Because i search about design with native not good/beautiful as design with html5.

Or can you give me solutions best design for android apps? (using sencha touch, jquery mobile, or something?)

Correct me if i wrong.

Thanks :)